# Java how to add a build command

Tags: java, netbeans, flatpak

I have an program written in Java. I have it in Netbeans 11.2.

I am trying to package it as a Flatpak. Printing works fine outside of the Flatpak.

One of its main elements is printing, but it has a fault when it goes to print:

`Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/lpr": error=2, No such file or directory`

Here is the full stack trace:

```
The job did not successfully complete
java.awt.print.PrinterIOException
        at java.desktop/sun.print.PSPrinterJob$PrinterSpooler.run(PSPrinterJob.java:746)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.desktop/sun.print.PSPrinterJob.endDoc(PSPrinterJob.java:805)
        at java.desktop/sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(RasterPrinterJob.java:1669)
        at highlighterpdf.PrintDocs2.PrintImage(PrintDocs2.java:64)
        at highlighterpdf.FileMenu.printActionPerformed(FileMenu.java:486)
        at highlighterpdf.FileMenu.access$1300(FileMenu.java:49)
        at highlighterpdf.FileMenu$14.actionPerformed(FileMenu.java:217)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6631)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6396)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5007)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4839)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4839)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/lpr": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:592)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:451)
        at java.desktop/sun.print.PSPrinterJob$PrinterSpooler.run(PSPrinterJob.java:739)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
        ... 46 more
```

I have been given the advice to:

"add a build command - sed -i s^/usr/bin/lpr^/app/bin/lpr^ thingy.jar"

How do I add a build command?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: its a lot not sure what to post?

Comment: You can post the stack trace exception and lines where exception occours

Comment: here is the stacktrace:   https://pastebin.com/bZkV1fy1

Comment: the address of the file is fixed in the JVM which is why I need to insert the build command